# provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: sql-server

```
try
        {
            //Create our connection strings
            string sSqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)) + "\\ClaimFiles.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            MessageBox.Show(sSqlConnectionString);

            //Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
            string sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM PA";
            SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString);
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn);
            SqlConn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show(SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
            SqlConn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //handle exception
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #: " + i + "\n" +
                    "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                    "ErrorNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].Number + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                    "Severity Level: " + ex.Errors[i].Class + "\n" +
                    "Server:" + ex.Errors[i].Server + "\n");
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessages.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Above is my code in C#, i'm using Microsoft SQL express. the code above is activated upon a click. When i run the code in Visual Studio everything works fine. But when i copy the folder of the project to a different computer(OS: Windows XP) and run the .exe file the program catches a SqlException:

> An error has occured while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Can someone help me with this, it would be a great help to solve this problem, because the program must run in a different computer. By the way program's target framework is .NET 3.5

Comment: Have you ensured that the service is running? Have you ensured that SQL Server Express is even installed on the second computer?

Comment: there is no SQL Server on the other computer.

Comment: is it required to have SQL server express on the othet computer?

Comment: Yes, unless you can connect to an existing SQL Server instance somewhere over the network, the connection string here certainly assumes that SQL Server is running locally. If it's not running locally, it has to be running somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Aaron Bertrand for your replies:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
> - Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an    instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application
>     converts    \ to . If you are not sure about your application,
>     please try both    Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your
>     connection string]
> - Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve    correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
> - Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server. If firewall is    enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP
>     port    1434 into exception.

This seems to be a good reference :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx